# H2 database: not able to copy multiple tables simultaneously from Oracle to H2 using Java concurrency

Tags: h2

I am trying to copy 30 tables from Oracle 11g database to H2 database during a process in my Java application. None of the tables are related.
To speed up the process I am creating 30 threads for each table and try to copy the tables simultaneously. I am able to start all threads, but as soon as one of thread start to execute the query, all other threads that hit the H2 db, went into monitor state from running state.

1. Is it not possible with H2 database to copy multiple table simultaneously or am I doing something wrong and need any special configuration while creating connection
2. Do anyone has any workaround for this problem.
3. Is it at least possible to read data from different tables simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

H2 is single threaded by default. To use the multi-threaded mode, [append `;MULTI_THREADED=1` to the database URL](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html?highlight=MULTI_THREADED&search=multi_thread#set_multi_threaded). Please note this feature is not fully tested; I suggest to use at least H2 version 1.4.x (and the MVStore) when using this feature.

Comment: Thank you Thomas
I am using the following url to create connection in each thread ->  jdbc:h2:file:C:\Core\Database\db4;MULTI_THREADED=1
Still only one thread is executing at a time, is my url correct? Anyway I'll try with the version you've mentioned.